# Multiple collections for Rigid Body

Tags: python, rigid-body-simulation

As written in [rigid body physics docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties/collisions.html#collections)

*Allows rigid body collisions allocate on different groups (maximum 20).*

How do I use Multiple collections for Rigid Body simulations ?

I see only one collection holder in the rigid body world.
It means support for nested collections under the given collection ?

clarification is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: just wanted to mention - 
the simulation will also affect the objects in the nested collections inside 
scene.rigidbody_world.collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer on the python part. But from what I understand about collections in *Rigid Body*:

If you keep the *RigidBodyWorld* collection that is selected by default in the *Scene panel > Rigid Body World*, and which is a kind of virtual collection, all the simulations will be played, regardless of the collection in which the objects are part of. If you choose another collection than *RigidBodyWorld*, the simulations will be played for the objects that are part of the selected collection only. Note that if you select the default collection back, it may bug (?), you just need to deactivate and reactivate the collection that the objects are part of in the *Outliner*:

[image]

If you select an object and go into the *Physics panel > Rigid Body > Collisions > Collections* there is another system of collections that maybe they should have called "layers" as it looks like a different system. Here you can select what layer the object is part of. The object won't interact with the ones that are part of another layer. If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> you can select several layers so that the object is part of several layers:

[image]

Comment: Well, I wish it could work differently and support multi collections using python.
thanks for the clarification.

Comment: oop sorry if it doesn't answer, I don't know anythig about python, maybe wait for another answer

Comment: It is answer what the docs means which is great,
thank you for your answer.